# Skipping test class execution in prod

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata

How options/parameters should be used so that the Salesforce does not run any test  classes (in prod) while deploying declarative metadata?

Comment: First option, Default ;-)

Comment: @CloudNinja, which parameter are you referring to ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should select Default. In production if the changeset has any apex code, it will run all local tests. If you are not deploying any code, no tests will be run.

From **[the deployment screen](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm)** (emphasis mine):

> **Default** Keeps the default behavior for all tests. In sandbox, no tests are executed. In production, all local tests are executed if your change sets contain Apex classes or triggers. Local tests are all tests, except the ones that originate from managed packages. **If your package doesn’t contain Apex components, no tests are run.**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a text reference for that description?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, Do you want me to update the link to the release notes instead of the screenshot?

Comment: I just mean if you copy-paste the description for that option and bold your highlighted text, your answer will be more accessible (and searchable).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Done.

Comment: I already voted for ya. Just cleaned it up a bit but obviously feel free to further tweak your answer if you so desire.